# Centering content middle page

Tags: html, css

I have created 4 info boxes using HTML and CSS but I cant seem to center the 4 boxes on the middle of the page (horizontal centering), I cant see what I'm doing wrong. Does anyone have any ideas? Anything helps, cheers!

```css
.infobox-list {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

ul, ol, li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-position: outside;
    list-style-type: none;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, ul, li, ol, form, fieldset {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul, menu, dir {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: disc;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    -webkit-padding-start: 40px;
}

.hr {
  border-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  margin-left:9px;
  width: 150px;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
    color: #555;
    min-width: 20em;
}

.info-boxes li {
  width: 245px;
    height: 345px;
    background: #e2ecf6;
    border: 0px solid #efefef;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 0 0px 0px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: scale(0.8); 
}

.ptext
{
  text-align:center;
}

.profile
{
  margin-top:40%;
  margin-left:-10px;
  width:75px;
  height:75px;
}

.performance
{
  margin-top:40%;
  margin-left:-1.5px;
  width:75px;
  height:75px;
}

.learning
{
  margin-top:40%;
  margin-left:-11px;
  width:75px;
  height:75px;
}

.team
{
  margin-top:40%;
  margin-left:-9px;
  width:75px;
  height:75px;
}

.smallicons
{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}

.everything {
  text-align:center;
}

.infobox-list li {
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight:lighter;
}

.info-boxes li .infobox {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 245px;
  width: 345px;
}

.info-boxes li .infobox:before { 
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  width: 160%; 
  height: 200%; 
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); /* fallback */
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(36deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(36deg);
  transform: rotate(36deg);
} 

.info-boxes li:hover .shade {
  animation-name: windowshade;
}

.info-boxes li .shade,
.info-boxes li:hover .shade {
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

section p {
  line-height: 1.3em;
  color: #6d6e71;
  width: 95%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  text-align:left;
}

p {
  display: block;
}

.info-boxes li .shade {
  position: absolute;
  width: 245px;
  height: 355px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #00688B;
  color: #fff;
  display: table;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 20px 10px 0;
  transform: translateY(-340px);
  animation-name: windowshade-out;
}

.info-boxes li .shade h3 {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: bold
}

.info-boxes li .shade p {
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  font-weight: normal
}

.ie9 .info-boxes li:hover .shade {
  top: 245px
}

.info-boxes li:hover a {
  text-decoration: none
}

@keyframes windowshade {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-340px)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0)
  }
}

@keyframes windowshade-out {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-340px)
  }
}
```

```html
<br style="line-height:100px;>"
<div class="everything">
<section class="info-boxes">
  <ul class="infobox-list">
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="infobox">
          <table>
            <tr>
          <img class="profile" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497365894/Profile-Icon_twnm83.png"></tr>
            <tr>
              <p class="ptext">Profile</P></tr></table>
                    </div>
        <div class="shade">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497301295/About-Me_dudglr.png">
              </td>
              <td><p>About Me</p><hr class="hr"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284615/Resume_tb7t02.png"
              </td>
              <td><p>Resume</p><hr class="hr"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497280574/Accountabilities_qfdcns.png"</td>
              <td><p>Accountabilities<p/><hr class="hr"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td><p></p></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="infobox">
          <table>
            <tr>
          <img class="performance" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497365894/Performance-Icon_bwevmx.png"></tr>
            <tr><p class="ptext">Performance</P></tr></table>
        </div>
        <div class="shade">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284615/Goals_aw4nso.png">
              </td>
              <td><p>Goals</p><hr class="hr"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284934/EA_n8lvj1.png"
              </td>
                <td><p>Effectiveness Assessment</p><hr class="hr"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284615/development_yfv6o1.png"
              </td>
              <td><p>Development Plan</p><hr class="hr"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497285433/resources_b3r88g.png"</td>
              <td><p>Resources<p/><hr class="hr"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td><p></p></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          </div>
       </a>
    </li>
    <li>
           <div class="infobox">
             <table>
               <tr>
             <img class="learning" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497365894/Learning-Icon_p8gqbk.png"></tr>
               <tr><p class="ptext">Learning</P></tr></table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="shade">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497297687/Training-Plan_v43ne7.png">
              </td>
              <td><p>Training Plan</p><hr class="hr"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497297687/Training-History_czttv1.png"
              </td>
                <td><p>Training History</p><hr class="hr"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497298863/coursefeedback_qdh1wm.png"
              </td>
              <td><p>Course Feedback</p><hr class="hr"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497299106/Favourites_y9gkce.png"</td>
              <td><p>Training Favourites<p/><hr class="hr"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td><p></p></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
    <li>
   <div class="infobox">
     <table>
       <tr>
     <img class="team" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497365894/TeamIcon_as9ynw.png"></tr>
       <tr><p class="ptext">Team</p></tr></table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="shade">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497300652/Team_iovnl5.png">
              </td>
              <td><p>Team</p><hr class="hr"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284615/Goals_aw4nso.png"
              </td>
                <td><p>Team Goals</p><hr class="hr"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284615/development_yfv6o1.png"
              </td>
              <td><p>Team Development</p><hr class="hr"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497297687/Training-Plan_v43ne7.png"
              </td>
              <td><p>Team Training</p><hr class="hr"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497301295/Approval_f9y1da.png"</td>
              <td><p>Approvals<p/><hr class="hr"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td><p></p></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>      
</ul> 
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: I could help answer this question, but I feel my efforts will be better placed commenting on the standard of your markup. Firstly, please don't use `table` for layout. Secondly, your `img` tags are not closed correctly. You have empty tags, which is not ideal.

Comment: @AlexThomas `<img>` is a *void-element*. Omitting the end tag is allowed, as per the [HTML5 Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements)

Comment: @Santi The closing slash is not specified for the `<img>` tag and should not be used because it does nothing and is ignored though it's not invalid. In any case, he doesn't have the closing right bracket in some instances. https://developers.whatwg.org/edits.html#the-img-element

Comment: @Rob Alex Thomas told OP that his "img tags are not closed correctly", which is simply untrue. I said nothing of them being invalid, I'm merely pointing out that this is misinformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your list is `display: inline-block;`, you can simply add a `text-align: center;` to your `.info-boxes` section. I'd also suggest removing the padding from your `<ul>` so that the items are truly centered:

```
.info-boxes {
    text-align: center;
}    

.infobox-list {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
}
```

---

**Full snippet:**

```css
 .info-boxes {
    text-align: center;
 }    

.infobox-list {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
}

ul, ol, li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-position: outside;
    list-style-type: none;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, ul, li, ol, form, fieldset {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul, menu, dir {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: disc;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    -webkit-padding-start: 40px;
}

.hr {
  border-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  margin-left:9px;
  width: 150px;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
    color: #555;
    min-width: 20em;
}

.info-boxes li {
  width: 245px;
    height: 345px;
    background: #e2ecf6;
    border: 0px solid #efefef;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 0 0px 0px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: scale(0.8); 
}

.ptext
{
  text-align:center;
}

.profile
{
  margin-top:40%;
  margin-left:-10px;
  width:75px;
  height:75px;
}

.performance
{
  margin-top:40%;
  margin-left:-1.5px;
  width:75px;
  height:75px;
}

.learning
{
  margin-top:40%;
  margin-left:-11px;
  width:75px;
  height:75px;
}

.team
{
  margin-top:40%;
  margin-left:-9px;
  width:75px;
  height:75px;
}

.smallicons
{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}

.everything {
  text-align:center;
}

.infobox-list li {
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight:lighter;
}

.info-boxes li .infobox {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 245px;
  width: 345px;
}

.info-boxes li .infobox:before { 
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  width: 160%; 
  height: 200%; 
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); /* fallback */
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(36deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(36deg);
  transform: rotate(36deg);
} 

.info-boxes li:hover .shade {
  animation-name: windowshade;
}

.info-boxes li .shade,
.info-boxes li:hover .shade {
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

section p {
  line-height: 1.3em;
  color: #6d6e71;
  width: 95%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  text-align:left;
}

p {
  display: block;
}

.info-boxes li .shade {
  position: absolute;
  width: 245px;
  height: 355px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #00688B;
  color: #fff;
  display: table;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 20px 10px 0;
  transform: translateY(-340px);
  animation-name: windowshade-out;
}

.info-boxes li .shade h3 {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: bold
}

.info-boxes li .shade p {
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  font-weight: normal
}

.ie9 .info-boxes li:hover .shade {
  top: 245px
}

.info-boxes li:hover a {
  text-decoration: none
}

@keyframes windowshade {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-340px)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0)
  }
}

@keyframes windowshade-out {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-340px)
  }
}
```

```html
<br style="line-height:100px;>"
<div class="everything">
<section class="info-boxes">
  <ul class="infobox-list">
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="infobox">
          <table>
            <tr>
          <img class="profile" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497365894/Profile-Icon_twnm83.png"></tr>
            <tr>
              <p class="ptext">Profile</P></tr></table>
                    </div>
        <div class="shade">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497301295/About-Me_dudglr.png">
              </td>
              <td><p>About Me</p><hr class="hr"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284615/Resume_tb7t02.png"
              </td>
              <td><p>Resume</p><hr class="hr"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497280574/Accountabilities_qfdcns.png"</td>
              <td><p>Accountabilities<p/><hr class="hr"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td><p></p></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="infobox">
          <table>
            <tr>
          <img class="performance" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497365894/Performance-Icon_bwevmx.png"></tr>
            <tr><p class="ptext">Performance</P></tr></table>
        </div>
        <div class="shade">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284615/Goals_aw4nso.png">
              </td>
              <td><p>Goals</p><hr class="hr"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284934/EA_n8lvj1.png"
              </td>
                <td><p>Effectiveness Assessment</p><hr class="hr"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284615/development_yfv6o1.png"
              </td>
              <td><p>Development Plan</p><hr class="hr"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497285433/resources_b3r88g.png"</td>
              <td><p>Resources<p/><hr class="hr"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td><p></p></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          </div>
       </a>
    </li>
    <li>
           <div class="infobox">
             <table>
               <tr>
             <img class="learning" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497365894/Learning-Icon_p8gqbk.png"></tr>
               <tr><p class="ptext">Learning</P></tr></table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="shade">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497297687/Training-Plan_v43ne7.png">
              </td>
              <td><p>Training Plan</p><hr class="hr"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497297687/Training-History_czttv1.png"
              </td>
                <td><p>Training History</p><hr class="hr"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497298863/coursefeedback_qdh1wm.png"
              </td>
              <td><p>Course Feedback</p><hr class="hr"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497299106/Favourites_y9gkce.png"</td>
              <td><p>Training Favourites<p/><hr class="hr"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td><p></p></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
    <li>
   <div class="infobox">
     <table>
       <tr>
     <img class="team" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497365894/TeamIcon_as9ynw.png"></tr>
       <tr><p class="ptext">Team</p></tr></table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="shade">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497300652/Team_iovnl5.png">
              </td>
              <td><p>Team</p><hr class="hr"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284615/Goals_aw4nso.png"
              </td>
                <td><p>Team Goals</p><hr class="hr"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497284615/development_yfv6o1.png"
              </td>
              <td><p>Team Development</p><hr class="hr"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497297687/Training-Plan_v43ne7.png"
              </td>
              <td><p>Team Training</p><hr class="hr"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><img class="smallicons" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/djxai1v1e/image/upload/v1497301295/Approval_f9y1da.png"</td>
              <td><p>Approvals<p/><hr class="hr"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td><p></p></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>      
</ul> 
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: are you talking about the 40px padding?

Comment: By default, a `<ul>` will have `left-padding` to offset its child items. Without removing this padding, your items would be shifted to the right rather than being true-center. If you want them to be shifted slightly right-of-center, then you can simply remove my `padding: 0px;`.

Comment: Are my logos, and the text under my logos (on the div before you hover) centered properly in the table? I had to use padding to center them but that doesn't seem like the right way to do it. The logos should all be centered in the middle (vertical and horizontal) of the cell and the text below it should be the same. I feel like I did something wrong.

Comment: I'm a bit confused - your question was asking how to center the four boxes on the screen, no?

Comment: Oh yeah, no you answered that, thanks for the help! Was just wondering if you knew anything about my other comment just so I don't have to post a new question.

Comment: Oh, well personally I'd consider using `flexbox` for full centering. Check out [this resource](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/), I believe it may help you a lot - not only in this, but you may be able to avoid using `<table>` elements, which is a huge no-no when it comes to layout/design.

Answer (score 0):

I would do what others were saying and use `text-align:center` in your section. Then you would have to make some adjustments still to make sure that you don't have extra padding or margins on the left side, which from the looks of it you might.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that the problem is in the first line of the body tag which is `<br style="line-height:100px;>"` , just put the double quotations inside the tag and it will be solved.
I test it in my browser and it worked.

Comment: actually I test it and it really affects, that is weird right ! @Santi

Comment: it is actually a syntax error `>"`  in the end of the line just do that `">` @Santi

Answer (score 0):

Add following code:

```
.infobox-list {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 0; 
}
```

Instead of

```
.infobox-list {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/ash06229/4exm16xo/5/

Answer (score -1):

You need to add css style

```
.info-boxes{text-align:center}
```